# How to make cocoapods `install` command fetch the latest changes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build-process, cocoapods, podspec

How to make cocoapods `install` command fetch the latest changes for pods that are referenced by `:git`, eg:  `pod SomePod, :git => https://github.com/Doe/SomePod.git` ?

I would expect that it should work like so, because it the Podfile.lock there isn't any information related to any revision.

Solutions that i can think of:

- stop using semantic versioning operators (~>, >= ...) and always run `pod update`
- in `pre_install` check the revision of the pod in the ~/.cocoapods/repos/SomePod against the one from origin and see if they differ, and let the user know that the pod is behind, maybe, somehow (`pod update SomePod`), even do the update, but this feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about this is `pod install` doesn't redownload things that already exist locally. What you want instead is `pod update`. You can also just update a single pod with `pod update SomePod`

Comment: True, but during development on an app, switching an different branches a couple of types a day, and every time you have to run `pod install` `compile` see it fail because you don't have the latest changes from SomePod then do the update is frustrating.